# Open terminal to locally forwarded port

Tags: ssh, terminal, port-forwarding, ubuntu-20.04

I am using `ssh` to access a remote server via local port forwarding. This however being the first time I'm using `ssh`, I'm not quite familiar with it. I am using this command

```
ssh -N -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -L local_port:destination_server_ip:remote_port remote_username@ssh_server_hostname
```

which then asks for a password that authenticates me successfully.

This may be an obvious question, but how do open a terminal session on the remote server (destination_server_ip)?

I've seen tutorials like [this](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example) which explain the local port forwarding but it doesn't seem to say how to open a terminal on the remote server.

Comment: By "remote server" you mean `destination_server_ip`, not `ssh_server_hostname`, right? If so, what is the service/daemon/program that listens on `destination_server_ip:remote_port`? Is it a telnet deamon? SSH server? `socat` that spawns a shell? or what? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes the "remote server " is `destination_server_ip`. As for the service that listens on the `destination_server_ip:remote_port` I don't know for sure, but I believe it is a SSH server. This is for a college subject that I'm working on, but I'm sort of left on my own.

Comment: *If* it's an SSH server then you need to run another local SSH client and connect to `localhost:local_port`. This is how you do it: `ssh -p local_port localhost` or `ssh ssh://localhost:local_port`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it does appear that `ssh -p local_port localhost` is working except for one small problem, it asks me for a password which I don't know, and an error saying: `Permission denied (publickey,password).` What exactly is this authentication for,? I am already authenticated once when I establish my connection to the destination server.

Comment: No, the connection you established with `ssh -L` is only to `remote_username@ssh_server_hostname`. Only if something (like another local `ssh`) connects to `localhost:local_port`, a connection is made to `destination_server_ip:remote_port` from `ssh_server_hostname`. The second connection uses the tunnel, but in every aspect it's a separate SSH connection. If you want to connect with SSH to `destination_server_ip` then you must authenticate to it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your command shown in the question is not intended for *just opening a shell at the remote system*. This is used to tunnel application access through the encrypted tunnel like a webbrowser access to remote an intranet server or for you SQL client to access the SQL server.

These applications will reach the remote server by accessing `localhost:local_port` instead of the unreachable remote address.

If you just want to open a terminal shell on the remote system then your command can be simpler:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa  remote_username@ssh_server_hostname
```

enter the password (of the key `id_rsa`)
... and you have your shell.

As you do not know the password of the remote_user, you are required to use the key-authentication as you have the key. The option `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` provides the key.

To reduce complexity for the daily handling you can configure this host access in the file: `~/.ssh/config`

```
# Your Project Server:
Host   REMOTE_SERVER
Port   REMOTE_PORT
User   REMOTE_USERNAME
IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
AddKeysToAgent  yes
```

Annotations to the config file :

- The key line is `Host ...`.
- All entries following this line are assigned to the server defined there, until the next `host`-line defines the next server (or the file ends).
- Global settings have to be written before the first `host`-line

The line `AddKeysToAgent yes` allows the ssh-agent to store the password of the key, so the next time you have not to enter the password again.

After configuring the  `~/.ssh/config`, your command to open a remote shell gets shorter:

```
ssh REMOTE_SERVER
```

Is this the answer you've expected?
Anything missing?